# golang regexp remove all blank lines

Tags: regex, go

I want to replace all blank lines and lines filled only with spaces/tabs using golangs regexp. I thought the following regexp should do the trick, 

    `` emptyLINE := regexp.MustCompile(`^\s*$`) ``

but was surprised, that the begin of line `^` and end of line `$` regexp tags do not work. They rather seem to signify the start/end of the whole string instead of just a line within the string, see

https://play.golang.org/p/WZ4flVtDMN

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:

Wiktors answer almost got me there, still I cannot remove all wanted lines:
https://play.golang.org/p/1IpETpFKCU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the `(?m)` inline modifier:

```
regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^\s*$`) 
                    ^^^^
```

The [MULTILINE modifier](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/) will make `^` match the start of the *line* and `$` will match the end of a *line*:

> `m`        multi-line mode: `^` and `$` match begin/end line in addition to begin/end text (default false)

Another thing to bear in mind is that `\s` matches `[\t\n\f\r ]` symbols. If you want to match all horizontal whitespaces, you may use `[ \t]` or `[\t\p{Zs}]`. That will let you stay inside the line bounds.

And another thing: `$` only asserts the position after a line break, it does not consume it, so, you need to actually match `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n` after `$` (if you need to remove the linebreaks, too).

This is what I came up with ([demo](https://play.golang.org/p/coiUzecTtO)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^\s*$[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+\s+\z`)
    in := ` 
      test 


    test  
     `
    want_empty := `   test 
    test    `
    fmt.Printf("have [%v]\n", in)
    fmt.Printf("want [%v]\n", want_empty)
    fmt.Printf("got  [%v]\n", re.ReplaceAllString(in, ""))
}
```

The `^\s*$[\r\n]*` - matches the start of a line, any 0+ whitespaces, assets the end of a line (`$`) and then matches 0+ LF/CR symbols.

The `[\r\n]+\s+\z` alternative matches 1 or more CR or LF symbols, 1+ whitespaces and then the unambiguous end of string `\z`, without it, `^\s*$[\r\n]*` won't match the last empty line.

Comment: Almost there,how can i remove the blank lines entirely?

https://play.golang.org/p/1IpETpFKCU

Comment: Try `regexp.MustCompile("(?m)^\\s*$[\r\n]*")` and then use `strings.Trim(re.ReplaceAllString(in, ""), "\r\n")`. See https://play.golang.org/p/yEfywMQZlV